# Problems with retopology after applying union to two cylinders

Tags: modeling, mesh, retopology

I would like to ask for some advice on how to retopologize after applying boolean operation union. In the pictures below, I'm using bevel and subdivision modifiers.

I've tried something like this:
[image]

But I'm still having problems with shading:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hello, could you please share this object (just the intersection)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots hello, here's the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/1739f9e2443e44ab8320ea6334e4bcf9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dissolve these edges and it will work fine in my opinion:

[image]